# Matching a value from a variable with a value in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to create a system in which administrators can grant access to people simply by putting their user ID in a database field, but more than 1 ID needs to be in the same column.

At the moment I have an array ($id_array) which when print_r'd looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => 256 [1] => 211 [2] => 212 [3] => 213 [4] => 214 [5] => 215 ) Array ( [0] => )
```

How would I use the current logged in user's ID ($user_id) and check to see if it is in the $id_array array?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

```
in_array($user_id, $id_array);
```